# How to transform a Logs-Based Metric label and the Google Cloud system timestamp (or user timestamp from a label) into a time series chart in Grafana?

Tags: logging, dashboard, grafana

I want to see a simple time series with the value of the label in a Grafana Time Series panel, and as input I use a Logs-Based Metric (LBM) that has the rows_count of a csv in it each day.

Since the time series always just show the Google Cloud Measures (changing the unit does not change the measures behind), I wonder whether I can use my values instead of the Google Cloud measure.

In my LBM that I make from the logs of a cloud function that outputs jsonPayload using `google.cloud.logging`, I have one value label and one timestamp label. I know that I cannot just change the y axis to my new value, it seems to be fixed by the LBM to the traffic, like `B/s` or the like.

Now I thought I should bring it into long format instead, using the "Transform" tab with its many functions. But after some testing, I cannot seem to get there: just having the timestamp of my logs or the system google timestamp (one of the two, and both are fine) on the x-axis and the value of my chosen label on the y-axis.

It seems I cannot use my own user-made log column for the time series charts on the y-axis, the values appear only as labels in the legend. And changing the data from wide to long format as I have tried it does not seem to solve it, or I have overseen some other nice function (but I have tried quite a few similar).

In short:

When I just use the LBM value label in group by (or in the alias using `{{metric.label.rows_count}}`), I see a time series chart of the GCP traffic, but not of the values.

Am I really forced to use the time server monitoring measure that GCP links to my LBM or  can I switch the used value of the y-axis?

###### Query tab:

[image]

###### Transform tab:

[image]

Since this does not seem to work, I will have to make the workaround of quering just the database that ingests the csv, but my aim was to see the rows_count in the logs of that csv as a step on its own. Strange if that is not possible, I must have misunderstood something.

How to transform a Logs-Based Metric and the Google Cloud system timestamp (or user timestamp from a label) into a time series chart in Grafana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of choosing `Counter` which

> collects the number of log entries matching a given filter

you need to choose `Distribution`

which

> collects numeric data from log entries matching a given filter:

[image]

With that LBM, you get the LBM values into the y-axis of a time series graph if you use the date(time) on the x-axis.

I could only get the values in the chart when I also added the regex, it seems as if units are added automatically which make the numerical values unreadable without regex. The official GCP docs [Creating a distribution metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/distribution-metrics#create-distribution) tells you to use `([0-9.]+)`.